# How to check if a string is a valid date in C

Tags: c, validation

I'm writing a function which checks if a string is a valid date.

I pass in any random string for example: "ted" or 11/34/67 or 9/10/13

In the function, a valid month is anything from 1-12 and a valid day is anything from 1-31.

My idea was to go through each string character by character. I would check the first character to see if it is a number and then convert it to an int if it was. Then I would test to see if it was a valid integer. However, I'm having trouble converting the character to an int.

```
int isDate(char* string)
{
     int num;
     if(isdigit(string[0]))
          num = strtol(string[0]);

}
```

Any help or ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: You might take a look at `strptime()`. It might save you a whole lot  of parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed can use strol to get parts of date, see `man 3 strol`:

```
int isDate(char* string)
{
    char *endptr;
    int base = 10;
    int year, month, day;

    month = strtol(string, &endptr, base);
    /* check month range here, return something on error */
    printf("month: %d\n", month);

    if (endptr[0] == '/') {
        year = strtol(endptr + 1, &endptr, base);
        /* check year range ... */
        printf("year: %d\n", year);
    } else {
        /* no year, error ... */
    }
    if (endptr[0] == '/') {
        day = strtol(endptr + 1, &endptr, base);
       /* check day range ... */
        printf("day: %d\n", day);
    } else {
        /* no day, error ... */
    }

    /* success, return something */
}
```

You may need to check *strtol()* calls for error too, read manpage. Sending *endptr + 1* can be dangerous, but it can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
num = strtol(string[0]);
```

`string[0]` is not a string, it is a `char`.

Use this way:

```
num = string[0] - '0';
```

Comment: When I do that and print out num: printf("%d\n", &num); I get 847005308

Comment: You are using wrong syntax for printing. Use `printf("%d\n", num);`